# Reset Django database while running

Tags: python, django, django-models, reset, django-postgresql

I'm trying to reset my database while Django project's running but I'm having a trouble. Django is constantly interacting with the database due to his mapping between database and models.

I'm using the module reset_db as following :

```
from django.core import management
management.call_command('reset_db',router='default',interactive = False)
```

I'm using postgres and, when this command is running, I have this error :

```
OperationalError: database "XXX" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 1 other session(s) using the database.
```

I tried to drop the database from psycopg2 but I still have this problem. 
I also tried the brute force, launch an external script who's killing all connexions :

```
os.system("bash myscript.sh")
```

My script :

```
psql -U myuser -d mybase -c "select pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.procpid) from pg_stat_activity where pg_stat_activity.datname='mybase';"
./manage.py reset_db --router=default --noinput
```

This one worked. However, as I killed all connections to database, my application doesn't answer (which is logical).

I have to reset all my base from the application. For example, in my administration pannel (which is not the one from Django), I have a button "Reset data" and, when clicked, it has to delete all data, do a syncdb and migrate.

Does anyone know how can I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: You'd be better off making this a script that shut down the app, drops the data tables and then syncdb. You really shouldn't be messing with the database while the app is on. You could end up with data loss. This is a really strange case, what is the specific reason you're wanting this?